# Kubernetes on Azure : connectex

Tags: azure, kubernetes, acs

Followed steps from the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-deployment) to create a K8s cluster using the Azure Portal. Tried using kubectl on a remote machine to check if it's working.  Got this error.

> Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 13.90.35.157:443: connectex:
>   A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I can SSH to the K8s master.  Tried `kubectl get nodes` from the master and got similar error.

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to say from such a description what went wrong, but as this is a new cluster ( and I'm saying this because sometimes k8s cluster gets deployed but doesn't really work, so ), I would suggest deleting it and creating a new one and\or creating it using the Azure Cli\Azure Cloud Shell.

Basically its as simple as:

```
az acs create -n acs-cluster -g acsrg1 -d applink789 --generate-ssh-keys
```

if you have the resource group created, if not you can create it with:

```
az group create -n acsrg1 -l "westus"
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, it seems you have **not** configured the Service Principal correctly. I use wrong service principal to deploy K8S in Azure, get the same error:

```
C:\Users>kubectl get nodes
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 13.90.27.73:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

You may need to check to ensure the credentials were provided accurately, and that the **configured Service Principal has read and write permissions to the target Subscription**.
If your Service Principal is misconfigured, none of the kubernetes components will come up in a healthy manner. We can check to see if this the problem:

```
root@k8s-master-6FEE48E1-0:~# journalctl -u kubelet | grep --text autorest
```

If you see output that looks like the following, it means you have not configured the service Principal correctly.

```
root@k8s-master-6FEE48E1-0:~# journalctl -u kubelet | grep --text autorest
Jun 01 01:58:47 k8s-master-6FEE48E1-0 docker[5522]: E0601 01:58:47.447321    6028 kubelet.go:1186] Cannot get Node info: failed to get external ID from cloud provider: autorest#WithErrorUnlessStatusCode: POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/1fcf418e-66ed-4c99-9449-d8e18bf8737a/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 failed with 400 Bad Request: StatusCode=400
Jun 01 01:58:47 k8s-master-6FEE48E1-0 docker[5522]: E0601 01:58:47.627128    6028 kubelet_node_status.go:70] Unable to construct api.Node object for kubelet: failed to get external ID from cloud provider: autorest#WithErrorUnlessStatusCode: POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/1fcf418e-66ed-4c99-9449-d8e18bf8737a/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 failed with 400 Bad Request: StatusCode=400
Jun 01 01:58:47 k8s-master-6FEE48E1-0 docker[5522]: E0601 01:58:47.885092    6028 kubelet_node_status.go:70] Unable to construct api.Node object for kubelet: failed to get external ID from cloud provider: autorest#WithErrorUnlessStatusCode: POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/1fcf418e-66ed-4c99-9449-d8e18bf8737a/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 failed with 400 Bad Request: StatusCode=400
```

More information about how to create /configure a service principal for ACS-Engin Kubernetes cluster, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-kubernetes-service-principal).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.